# How to change visibility of element using a classname

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this class name:

```
.mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 240px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: width .25s, min-width .25s;
  right: 900px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

The current visibility and I want to make it visible onclick:

```
function search() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder')[0].style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

and

```
<a onclick="search()">Search</a>
```

but it does not seem to be working and I have no idea why. Any ideas on how to fix this? And yes, I did check that the `.mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder` is an `<element class="mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder">` not an ID. Thanks!

Comment: Do you need an href on the anchor for it to be clickable?

Comment: How are you calling the function? `search()`, also, are you making sure the element is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a classname to the element when you click on the `search` button.

```
//--- style ----//
.mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 240px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: width .25s, min-width .25s;
  right: 900px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder .show {
  visibility: visible;
}

//----- javascript code ------//

function search() {
  let el_mapboxgl = document.getElementsByClassName('mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder')[0];
  el_mapboxgl.className += " show";
}
```

Please let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 1):

Add this -->

```
.mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder .show {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

and this javascript code ---->

```
function search() {
  let el_mapboxgl = document.getElementsByClassName('mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder')[0];
  el_mapboxgl.className += " show";
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears for you, you just have an offset to the right by 900px, specify 0px or the required number of pixels in the visibility zone if you have it on the left side!